# how to achieve master detail table data insertion in MVC 4 code first approch

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've been struggling to achieve the following logic for customer and their contact persons in MVC 4 EF code first approch.

---

customer table

```
 public int ID { get; set; }

 public string Name{ get; set; }

 public string Address { get; set; }
```

---

customer_contact table

```
 public int CustomerID { get; set; }

 public string ContactName { get; set; }

 public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

 public string Email { get; set; }
```

In this scenario one customer get more than one contact details with foreign key reference. Please any one guide me to achieve this. Thanks and advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your design should look like following if we consider one to many relationship in EF

customer table(Assume that it **Customer** class)

```
 public int CustomerID { get; set; }

 public string Name{ get; set; }

 public string Address { get; set; }

 public List<CustomerDetail> CustomerDetails{get; set; }
```

customer_contact table(Assume that it **CustomerDetail** class)

```
 public int CustomerDetailId{ get; set; }

 public string ContactName { get; set; }

 public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

 public string Email { get; set; }

 public int CustomerID { get; set; }

 public Customer Customer {get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add navigation properties to allow you to do master/detail inserts:

In the `Customer` class:

```
public virtual ICollection<CustomerDetail> CustomerDetails{ get; set; }
```

In the `CustomerDetails` class:

```
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

Then to insert a customer with details:

```
var customer = new Customer { Name="", Address="" };
context.Customers.Add(customer);

var customerDetails = new CustomerDetails { ContactName="", Customer=customer };
context.CustomerDetails.Add(customerDetails);

context.SaveChanges();
```